# How to calculate big combinatorics amount in tsql

Tags: t-sql, combinations, factorial, bigint

In sql2014 I have a table with 4 integers (W,X,Y,Z) and a bigint B.
B = C(X,Z)*C(W-X;Y-Z) where C(n,k) stands for combinations of k objects taken from n objects , that is, the usual n!/[k!(n-k)!]

The highest value of W,X,Y and Z is 40 so that the biggest B is 1.37847E+11
I can calculate the correct values using Excel (using the function COMBIN) but I can't to the same in SQL. I can generate the table with all the combinations of W,X,Y,Z that i need but when I try to calculate B for big values I don't know how to treat things like "40!".

I would like to use a CTE with preinserted values of factorial, something like:

```
;WITH factorials AS(
SELECT 2 as N, 2 AS F
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,6
UNION ALL...
)
```

but i dont know how to store 40! and the like.

Using .NET to fill the table is not an option, it should be made by SQL.

I even thought of using a table like the CTE before and storing the factorial in two or three columns, the first storing billions, the second storing billions of billions and so on (using INTs) but then I don't know how to make divisions among numbers stored like this, as in (Ax10^9+B)/(Cx10^9+D).

How do I manage integers larger than bigint in tsql?

Comment: right now i am thinking about good old division among polynomials... and it seems almost trivial... but it's not! because i still need to handle too big numbers probably

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure this isn't a complete solution, but maybe it will give you some ideas on how to get started. Perhaps you could make this a stored procedure and pass in @n and @k

Using DOUBLE doesn't seem to cause any problems when I cast it back to BIGINT.  Perhaps someone else can comment on the obvious dangers of doing this.

```
DECLARE @final_value DOUBLE PRECISION
DECLARE @n INT = 40
DECLARE @k INT = 20

;WITH CTE AS 
(
SELECT 1 AS num,CAST(1 AS DOUBLE PRECISION) AS factorial
UNION ALL
SELECT num+1,CAST(factorial*(num+1)AS DOUBLE PRECISION) FROM CTE
WHERE CTE.num < 40
)

SELECT * INTO #temp_numbers FROM CTE 

SET @final_value = (SELECT factorial FROM #temp_numbers WHERE num = @n) /
    (SELECT factorial FROM #temp_numbers WHERE num = @k) / 
    (SELECT factorial FROM #temp_numbers WHERE num = (@n-@k))  

PRINT CAST(@final_value AS BIGINT)
DROP TABLE #temp_numbers
```

Comment: this is EXACTLY what I needed. I had the chance today to apply your answer to my case and it works perfectly and very fast. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Please check decimal and numeric data types over here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx